# python: Find associated value from 2 lists

Tags: python

Sorry to pollute with such a routine question, but:

If I have 2 lists, for example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

list2 = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140]
```

how would I find the value associated with 3 in list1 (answer is 60)

in this case 1 is associated with 20, 2 w/ 40, and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to find the associated value for many different values in `list1`, or do this just once?

Comment: A dictionary is a better structure for what you (seem to) want

Comment: I'll want to do it many times.  I was going to set up a for loop for list1 and try to get associated values from list2

Comment: yes, thanks.  zip was what I wanted.  The post from Cyber got me running..  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zip them and make a dictionary.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> list2 = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140]
>>> dict(zip(list1,list2))
{1: 20, 2: 40, 3: 60, 4: 80, 5: 100, 6: 120, 7: 140}

>>> l = dict(zip(list1,list2))

>>> l[2]
40

>>> l[3]
60
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates in `list1`?

Comment: Thanks but there won't be in my case.  This solution is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> list2 = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140]
>>> zip(list1, list2)
[(1, 20), (2, 40), (3, 60), (4, 80), (5, 100), (6, 120), (7, 140)]
>>>
```

Of course, as @wnnmaw says, a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) would probably be better here:

```
>>> dict(zip(list1, list2))
{1: 20, 2: 40, 3: 60, 4: 80, 5: 100, 6: 120, 7: 140}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reason for keeping them in arrays, use this answer. *Else, please make them into a dictionary, as suggested in other answers*

When you say "associated" the real question you're trying to ask is:

*"What value is at the same index as (whatever value) in this other list?"*

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list2 = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140]

print list2[list1.index(3)] # 60
```